# Loading Property Files in WSO2 MI Serverr API during Startup without Class Mediator

Tags: properties, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm working with WSO2 Micro Integrator (MI) Server and I have a set of property files that I need to access within the API using a function like get-property('propName'). However, I want these properties to be loaded during the server startup, without using a class mediator to load the files and set the properties every time.

Is there a recommended approach or best practice specific to WSO2 MI Server for achieving this? I'm looking for a solution that allows the properties to be loaded once during server startup. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Tags: wso2 [wso2-micro-integrator], [api], [property-files], [class-mediator], [server-startup]

I need to get that property with in API by using xpath expressions like get-property('file','propertyName')

Answer (score 0):

This is supported OOB by Micro Integrator. You can add your properties to a file named `file.properties` and place it in the `<MI_HOME>/conf` directory and it will be picked up automatically. If you have a custom properties file, let's say `custom.properties` you can pass the file path on server startup like below by adding it to the startup script so it will be loaded.

```
-Dproperties.file.path=/home/user/ei_configs/dev/custom.properties
```

Once the file is loaded. You can read the properties as Properties like below.

```xml
<property name="someProp" expression="get-property('file','propName')" scope="default" />
```

Read more [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/injecting-parameters/#using-a-file)

**Update**

As you can pass multiple files, as a workaround you can create a shell script or batch script based on the environment, to read multiple properties files and merge them to a single file. You can add this script to `micro-integrator.sh` so it will be executed on server startup. An sample script blow.

```bash
# Assume that the properties files are available the location you are executing the server startup script.

output_file="${CARBON_HOME}/conf/file.properties"

for properties_file in *.properties; do
    if [ -f "$properties_file" ]; then
        cat "$properties_file" >> "$output_file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: That is Ok For One Properties File But I Have May Property Files How To Load Them.

Comment: @Rocky check the updated answer.